# Whats the difference between blog_info('stylesheet_url') difference get_stylesheet_uri()

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, codex

The question is in the title really. What is the difference between blog_info('stylesheet_url') difference get_stylesheet_uri(), and if it's a case that one is newer then which.

The codex says:

> 'stylesheet_url' - Returns the primary CSS (usually style.css) file URL of the active theme. Consider using get_stylesheet_uri() instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url` ) uses `get_stylesheet_uri()` function, so there is no difference. `get_stylesheet_uri()` is newer

Comment: thanks - actually do you have any idea why they'd be bothered writing a new function if there was an old one there that did the job - less typing ?

Comment: You're very welcome. I think they did this because of better performance.